# Javascript number Reverse on button click

Tags: javascript, html, button

I'm trying to reverse the number entered by the user on button click. I'm getting the number to output, but it's not in reverse. Here is my code.

```
<button id="btn"> Number Reverser </button>

<p id="para"></p>

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", reverseNumber);

function reverseNumber () {
    var number = prompt("Type a number you want reversed");
    return document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = number.split("").reverse().join("");
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your code seems to work, I don't see any issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", reverseNumber);


function reverseNumber()  
{  
    let number = prompt("Type a number you want reversed");
    let numReverse = number.split("").reverse().join("");
    document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = numReverse;   
}
```

```html
<button id="btn"> Number Reverser </button>

<p id="para"></p>
```

**Note:** Above code will work for string reversal as well.

Comment: Thank you good sir. Whats the logic behind number = number + ""; ?

Comment: I was just trying to make sure that number is converted to string. But that is not necessary because the number is already of type string.

Answer (score 1):

You should convert `number` to `string` before reverse it, so you must include `.toString()` between `number` and `.split("")`

Comment: Prompt values are already of string type you dont have to change it.

Comment: Someone told me that all prompt values are actually strings, is this true?

Comment: Yes it is, and btw I still dont see the problem in your code

Comment: @DanPhilip you are right, Prompt values already are string. The original code should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine if this is the output you are expecting.

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", reverseNumber);

function reverseNumber () {
    var number = prompt("Type a number you want reversed");
    return document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = number.split("").reverse().join("");
}
```

```html
<button id="btn"> Number Reverser </button>

<p id="para"></p>
```

Comment: I'm going to blame user error on this one. I think I typed in '121' and it outputted '121'

Comment: *facepalm* wheres the coffee